# Ionic 2 : Is there any way to test SQLite plugin with browser?

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I've implemented follow this link.
[Use SQLite In ionic 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/)
And as I known that SQLite native plugin is not support browser platform for now in Ionic 2 last version (rc6).

So, when I run ionic serve on the browser it will appear the message like below in console log.

```
Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but it's not installed.
Install the SQLite plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage'
```

So I cannot test storage query with the browser, is there any way to test SQLite plugin (or use other storage query plugin like WebSQL) with ionic serve on browser.

Comment: Some plugins work with `ionic platform add browser` but not this one I guess.. https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/297

Comment: Some code of what you have tried might be useful. SQLite is supported fairly well with ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/